Ros1 topic_tools::ShapeShifter for Service callbacks?
I am working in ros melodic and I have a node that creates a ros::ServiceServer and binds it to a service callback. I want this service callback to be generic since I would always access the same field in the service request. For example, let's say that I have 3 different srv files that all have in common a Request field of type string named message.
Service1.srv
bool enable
string message
---

Service2.srv
uint8 state
string message
---

Service3.srv
string url
string message
---

Is there any way to have a generic service callback with a tool similar to topic_tools::ShapeShifter for when I only need to access the message field in the request, which is the same across services types.
Thanks in advance.
